# decompress() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input_path'

Tags: python, tkinter, compression, typeerror, lossless

So my problem is integrating Huffman's coding into Tkinter. So the idea is to use a file explorer I made and allow the user to select the file they want to compress or decompress. The Huffman's coding will perform lossless compression and create a .bin file (credit goes to Bhrigu Srivastava https://youtu.be/JCOph23TQTY).

The compression part of the code works fine but not when I try to decompress the `.bin` file. I get the error as mentioned in the title above `TypeError: decompress() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input_path'`

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import heapq


class HuffmanCoding:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.heap = []
        self.codes = {}
        self.reverse_mapping = {}

    class HeapNode:
        def __init__(self, char, freq):
            self.char = char
            self.freq = freq
            self.left = None
            self.right = None

        # defining comparators less_than and equals
        def __lt__(self, other):
            return self.freq < other.freq
    
        def __eq__(self, other):
            if (other == None):
                return False
            if (not isinstance(other, HeapNode)):
                return False
            return self.freq == other.freq

    # functions for compression:

    def make_frequency_dict(self, text):
        frequency = {}
        for character in text:
            if not character in frequency:
                frequency[character] = 0
            frequency[character] += 1
        return frequency

    def make_heap(self, frequency):
        for key in frequency:
            node = self.HeapNode(key, frequency[key])
            heapq.heappush(self.heap, node)

    def merge_nodes(self):
        while (len(self.heap) > 1):
            node1 = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
            node2 = heapq.heappop(self.heap)

            merged = self.HeapNode(None, node1.freq + node2.freq)
            merged.left = node1
            merged.right = node2

            heapq.heappush(self.heap, merged)

    def make_codes_helper(self, root, current_code):
        if (root == None):
            return

        if (root.char != None):
            self.codes[root.char] = current_code
            self.reverse_mapping[current_code] = root.char
            return

        self.make_codes_helper(root.left, current_code + "0")
        self.make_codes_helper(root.right, current_code + "1")

    def make_codes(self):
        root = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
        current_code = ""
        self.make_codes_helper(root, current_code)

    def get_encoded_text(self, text):
        encoded_text = ""
        for character in text:
            encoded_text += self.codes[character]
        return encoded_text

    def pad_encoded_text(self, encoded_text):
        extra_padding = 8 - len(encoded_text) % 8
        for i in range(extra_padding):
            encoded_text += "0"

        padded_info = "{0:08b}".format(extra_padding)
        encoded_text = padded_info + encoded_text
        return encoded_text

    def get_byte_array(self, padded_encoded_text):
        if len(padded_encoded_text) % 8 != 0:
            print("Encoded text not padded properly")
            exit(0)

        b = bytearray()
        for i in range(0, len(padded_encoded_text), 8):
            byte = padded_encoded_text[i:i + 8]
            b.append(int(byte, 2))
        return b

    def compress(self):
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(self.path)
        output_path = filename + ".bin"

        with open(self.path, 'r+') as file, open(output_path, 'wb') as output:
            text = file.read()
            text = text.rstrip()

            frequency = self.make_frequency_dict(text)
            self.make_heap(frequency)
            self.merge_nodes()
            self.make_codes()

            encoded_text = self.get_encoded_text(text)
            padded_encoded_text = self.pad_encoded_text(encoded_text)

            b = self.get_byte_array(padded_encoded_text)
            output.write(bytes(b))

        print("Compressed")
        return output_path

    """ functions for decompression: """

    def remove_padding(self, padded_encoded_text):
        padded_info = padded_encoded_text[:8]
        extra_padding = int(padded_info, 2)

        padded_encoded_text = padded_encoded_text[8:]
        encoded_text = padded_encoded_text[:-1 * extra_padding]

        return encoded_text

    def decode_text(self, encoded_text):
        current_code = ""
        decoded_text = ""

        for bit in encoded_text:
            current_code += bit
            if current_code in self.reverse_mapping:
                character = self.reverse_mapping[current_code]
                decoded_text += character
                current_code = ""

        return decoded_text

    def decompress(self, input_path):
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(self.path)
        output_path = filename + "_decompressed" + ".txt"

        with open(input_path, 'rb') as file, open(output_path, 'w') as output:
            bit_string = ""

            byte = file.read(1)
            while (len(byte) > 0):
                byte = ord(byte)
                bits = bin(byte)[2:].rjust(8, '0')
                bit_string += bits
                byte = file.read(1)

            encoded_text = self.remove_padding(bit_string)

            decompressed_text = self.decode_text(encoded_text)

            output.write(decompressed_text)

        print("Decompressed")

        return output_path


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.config(background="white")
        self.path = None
        self.label_file_explorer = tk.Label(self, text="Menu", fg="blue",
                                            width="300", height="2",
                                            font="Helvetica 15 bold")
        self.label_file_explorer.pack()
        self.button_explore = tk.Button(self, text="Browse Files", fg="blue",
                                        font="Arial 15", relief=tk.GROOVE, width=20,
                                        command=self.browse_files)
        self.button_explore.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.button_exit = tk.Button(self, text="Close Program", width=20,
                                     font="Arial 15", relief=tk.GROOVE,
                                     # destroy root
                                     command=self.master.destroy)
        self.button_exit.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.button_compress = tk.Button(self, text="Compress", width=20,
                                         font="Arial 15", relief=tk.GROOVE,
                                         command=self.but_comp)
        self.button_compress.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.button_decompress = tk.Button(self, text="Decompress", width=20,
                                           font="Arial 15", relief=tk.GROOVE,
                                           command=self.but_decomp)
        self.button_decompress.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def browse_files(self):
        file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                               title="Select a File",
                                               filetypes=(("all files", "*.*"),
                                                          ("text files", "*.txt*")))

        if file_name == "":  # if Cancel
            return
        else:
            self.label_file_explorer.configure(text="Selected File: " + file_name)
            self.path = file_name

    def but_comp(self):
        if self.path:
            H = HuffmanCoding(self.path)
            H.compress()

    def but_decomp(self):
        if self.path:
            H = HuffmanCoding(self.path)
            H.decompress()
```

Comment: Please compress the code to a [mre]

Comment: You have `command=but_comp`. That means that when the button is click it will call `but_comp()` with no arguments but your code expects 1 argument (`file_name`). Also please don't define classes inside other classes. Also why do you have an empty class called `file_name`? Please read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

The `file_name` variable is a local variable in the `browseFiles` function.
Outside of this function, the name 'file_name'  is not defined.

You can combine tkinter code into one class. In the class, we can create `self` attributes and use them in any function within the class.

You can start with this example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


class HuffmanCoding:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        
    def compress(self):
        print("compress:", self.path)
        
    def decompress(self):
        print("decompress:", self.path)


# tkinter app, essentially a tk.Frame placed in the root window       
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.config(background="white")
        self.path = None
        self.label_file_explorer = tk.Label(self, text="Menu", fg="blue",
                                            width="300", height="2",
                                            font="Helvetica 20 bold")
        self.label_file_explorer.pack()
        self.button_explore = tk.Button(self, text="Browse Files", fg="blue",
                                        font="Arial 15", relief=tk.GROOVE,
                                        command=self.browse_files)
        self.button_explore.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.button_exit = tk.Button(self, text="Close Program",
                                     font="Arial 15", relief=tk.GROOVE,
                                     # destroy root
                                     command=self.master.destroy)
        self.button_exit.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.button_compress = tk.Button(self, text="Compress",
                                         font="Arial 15", relief=tk.GROOVE,
                                         command=self.but_comp)
        self.button_compress.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.button_decompress = tk.Button(self, text="Decompress",
                                           font="Arial 15", relief=tk.GROOVE,
                                           command=self.but_decomp)
        self.button_decompress.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def browse_files(self):
        file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                               title="Select a File",
                                               filetypes=(("all files", "*.*"),
                                                          ("text files", "*.txt*")))
    
        if file_name == "": # if Cancel
            return
        else:
            self.label_file_explorer.configure(text="Selected File: " + file_name)
            self.path = file_name


    def but_comp(self):
        if self.path:
            H = HuffmanCoding(self.path)
            H.compress()

    def but_decomp(self):
        if self.path:
            H = HuffmanCoding(self.path)
            H.decompress()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Compression Utility")
root.geometry("800x600")
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
# the last path stored in the data attribute
# of the instance of the Application class
print(app.path)
```

Alternatively, you can also use [Radiobuttons](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#radiobutton) instead of regular buttons. Instead of buttons "Compress" and "Decompress".

Comment: After adding the Huffman Code, the `but_comp` works but not the `but_decomp`. `decompress() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input_path'` is all I get.

Comment: It looks like input_path is the path selected by the user. You can pass self.path to the function: H.decompress(self.path).

Comment: Or remove this parameter altogether, as in the compress function.

Comment: I tried to pass the `self.path` through the function. It doesn't output the `TypeError` now which is good. But when I use `H.decompress(self.path)` on the compressed `.bin` file, the new `.txt` is empty, even though the .bin file had data.

Comment: Also I've to have the compression function as part of the code